# non-static variable CAN be accessed by static main method through calling class object .how?

Tags: java, oop, static-methods, main-method

A nonstatic variable can be accessed through the static main method by creating an object of that class. how is this possible?

the object-oriented rule is non-static variable can not be accessed by static method because While we run a class, first static blocks/ static variable initialization happens. Static block gets executed when a class is loaded into JVM. so we can't access nonstatic variable inside executed static method. But why only this scenario no compilation error? please give me a explanation

**This is allowed**

```
 public class Thread1 extends Thread{   
        int s ;
    }
        public class MainThread {
        int y =89;
            public static void main(String[] args)  {
            Thread1 j = new Thread1();
            System.out.println(j.s=43);
            }

        }
```

**This is not allowed why ???**

```
public class MainThread {
int y =89;
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

    Thread1 j = new Thread1();
    System.out.println(y);
    }

}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Focus on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2559596/522444) in the duplicate.

Comment: *This is not allowed why ???* Because `y` is not static, and you are trying to access it from a static context (the `main` method is static).

Comment: You'd need `static int y = 89`

Comment: @BackSlash I agree with your point but that not the case for me.i know non-static can not b accessed  through static field.. but my question is inside static main method access the non-static variable is allowed by creating class object  .. check ma code thanks

Comment: @B_Ali_Code It's because you are accessing it through an instance. In the second example you have no instance of class `MainThread`